# How are filters in a convolutional neural network trained through backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to implement a convolutional neural network from scratch. The problem is that I don't understand how filters are learned in CNNs.

I implemented a feedforward neural network from scratch before and I understand how backpropagation works for them. I also understand the basic CNN architecture. But how to compute the updated filters?

I don't want to use libraries like tensorflow because I want to understand the concepts behind all of this.

Answer (score 0):

The backpropagation through CNN is principally the same as through the feed-forward layer. You can imagine the CNN as a sliding window applying the same feedforward layer on every window of your the input. (You just take all values which are in the window and arrange them in a single long vector.)

You can compute the gradients of the parameters independently for each window. Because you apply the same parameters in each window, you can sum the gradients from each window and use the gradients to update and use them to update the parameters of the filter.

P.S. It might be a good exercise to write the back-propagation yourself, but you hardly can reach the efficiency of the frameworks.